# how to get class attribute by beautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an html code as follows:

```
<span class="attribute-value">
<i class="icon icon_male_symbol"></i>
<i class="icon icon_female_symbol"></i>
</span>
```

I want get result like this:

```
icon_male_symbol,icon_female_symbol
```

How can i do?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post your code trial?

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to get the class attributes of the tags and splicing them with ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to identify `span` tag using `find()` then need to `find_all()` all i tag then get attribute `class` which returns as list and then get the `last index value.`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<span class="attribute-value">
<i class="icon icon_male_symbol"></i>
<i class="icon icon_female_symbol"></i>
</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('span',class_='attribute-value').find_all('i'):
    print(item['class'][-1])
```

Comment: very thankful according to your answer, based on your answer, I have a better idea

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span class="attribute-value">
<i class="icon icon_male_symbol"></i>
<i class="icon icon_female_symbol"></i>
</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
clazz = ','.join(item['class'][-1] for item in soup.find('span', class_='attribute-value').find_all('i'))
print(clazz)
```